# Navigate to settings page

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I am new to Dynamics.

I am trying to navigate to Settings page in Dynamics 365 but I am unable to do.

I am logging to the Dynamics 365 home page it's taking me to below page.

[image]

After that when I click on the `Dynamics 365 - Custom App`.

[image]

I don't see the below page. How to navigate to the below page?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you have difficulty in finding the navigation tricks. :)

Try this. Click on the Dynamics 365 banner if you are not seeing the Marketing or Sales option next to that Dynamics 365 (I could not see that in your 2nd screenshot).

Then the small caret icon next to Marketing or Sales is the key spot to move forward.

[image]